# Annotation Retrieval given the URI

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I want to retrieve the annotations of a service ( in particular @RolesAllowed ) given the URI corresponding to the service.
Here an example:

The service:

```
@GET
@Path("/example")
@RolesAllowed({ "BASIC_USER", "ADMIN" })
public Response foo() {
    //Service implementation 
}
```

I want to retrieve { "BASIC_USER", "ADMIN" } given the String "/example".

I use RestAssured for testing so, if possible, I prefer a solution with the latter.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with RestAssured, but I wrote the following Junit test and it works. Perhaps you can adapt it to work with RestAssured.

First the Service:

```
public class Service {

  @GET
  @Path("/example")
  @RolesAllowed({ "BASIC_USER", "ADMIN" })
  public Response foo() {
    return new Response();
}
```

}

And this is the corresponding Junit test:

```
@Test
public void testFooRoles() throws Exception {
    Method method = Service.class.getMethod("foo");
    Annotation path = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(javax.ws.rs.Path.class);
    assertTrue(((Path) path).value().equals("/example"));

    RolesAllowed annotation = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    List<String> roles = Arrays.asList(annotation.value());
    assertEquals(2, roles.size());
    assertTrue(roles.contains("BASIC_USER"));
    assertTrue(roles.contains("ADMIN"));
}
```